# jQuery siblings is not working

Tags: jquery, css, block, attr, preventdefault

I need to make an article visible (display none by default) and make all the siblings articles with any id (any `<article id={xx}></article>` excluding the visible id) will be display none.

Small tweak needed here :

jQuery :

```
$('article a').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
     $('article[id='+id+']').css("display","block").siblings($('article[id='+id+']')).css({"display":"none"});
});
```

Comment: provide your html too

Comment: It probably doesn't help that your html is invalid. At least, from the code shown it appears that you have used the same id for more than one element (the anchor and the article), which is invalid.

Comment: YOU ARE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT !!! THANKS !!! so it's better to change it to class or change the link to <a herf="somedir/javascriptIsDisabled.php" id="gotoArticle[1]"> or is it better to give it a class name like <a herf="somedir/javascriptIsDisabled.php" class="1">

Answer (score 4):

hehe I found the solution by myself:

```
    $('article[id='+id+']').css("display","block").siblings($('article[id]')).css({"display":"none"});
```

many thanks to myself :D

... AND THIS IS THE IMPROVED VERSION

```
$('article[id='+id+']').show().siblings('article[id]').hide();
```

Comment: you can replace it with `$(this).show().siblings('article[id]').hide();`

Comment: hehe this is exactly what I did before I saw your post :D

Comment: @ArunPJohny - `$(this)` won't work, because `this` is the clicked anchor element, not the article element.

Comment: @ArunPJohny YES YOU ARE RIGHT ! THIS IS MY WORKING CODE :  $('article[id='+id+']').show().siblings('article[id]').hide();

Comment: @nnnnnn then we have a bigger problem because of duplicate ids... also it could be fixed with `$(this).closest('article').show().siblings('article[id]').hide();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I thought of `.closest()` at first, but I don't think the anchor is inside the associated article (because if it was it would be hidden too and couldn't be clicked).

Comment: I Can't use closest because I want to display an article from different section on the page...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to place a selector in the siblings method.

```
$('article[id='+id+']').show().siblings('article').hide();
```

Take that back, if you have other elements that aren't an article.. You would need to specify the article tag.  But the "[id]" is not needed.

Comment: I DO need the id beacuse I have some visible article and some non visible articles some of them with id's and the visible ones don't have any id